# Ubuntu Server unable to connect to Wifi or Ethernet

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, internet, ethernet

I just dual boot my Windows 11 PC with Ubuntu server 18.04, I could not get to the internet by any means. When I run ifconfig -a, it only returns lo. Since I could not get any Internet connection, there are many troubleshooting that I can't do.

I am suspecting is it because I am using an older kernel that could not compatible with the new ethernet and network controller. I am using 4.15.0-156-generic.

Any suggestions are most welcomed, I have struggled with this for a long time.

Comment: Try an Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 LiveUSB. Enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment. See if your network hardware is detected by that newer kernel.

Comment: Look at the startup log with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.

Comment: The Ubuntu you are using is the 2018-April release (ie. 18.04) so it won't know about later hardware because of the choice you made (ie. an old release).  Don't forget the five years of support for that release has only *months* to go, so why choose that much older release, especially on possibly newer hardware? or is this install intended to be used only short-term?  (5 years of *standard* support from 2018-April is 2023-April don't forget)

Comment: I have to stick to Ubuntu 18.04 because my company's codes are using it. I tried Ubuntu Server 22.04, and there is no network connection problem, but there are too many bugs when running the old codes. Is there any way I can use the Ubuntu Server 18.04 with latest kernel?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has two kernel stacks; the GA stack is the original stack that came with 18.04 & default for Server installs (4.15), but you have a second HWE stack that upgraded during the first ~15 months life of the product and reached it's final 5.4 kernel at 18.04.5, refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   All other options (excluding OEM available for particular hardware) require more maintenance as GA & HWE are the *supported* options for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.